# html form vertical textfield

Tags: jquery, html, css

can some one help me creating a vertical text field. actually I want to create a email subscription form in which I want to place a text field which can only take one character per row.

Comment: Should the letters also be rotated 90°? Or should it be like `a<newline>b<newline>c<newline>` with not rotated letters?

Comment: don't need to rotate letters, should be like a newline than b and so on

Comment: This sounds like a weird requirement. Can you explain, why you want to do this, because there may be better ways to do it, like multiple text inputs with `maxlength=1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like `<textarea style="height: 5em; width: 0.8em;" ></textarea>` (this will display the characters vertically). You may have to play with the height and width.

Comment: it's really help full and works fine initially but when the text grows from it's existing height it's showing up a scrollbar. to hide the scrollbar I have added overflow hidden but in this case it's hiding the overflow text. Is there a possibility to scroll the text upward when it reaches the end of the field

Comment: How about `<textarea style="height: 5em; width: 1em; overflow: hidden" onkeyup="this.scrollTop = this.scrollHeight" ></textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

The `writing-mode` and `filter` properties of css can be used make a vertical effect to a `textarea`. Following is an example html page, using these properties is a class

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
> <style type="text/css">
>   .verticaltext {
>       writing-mode: tb-rl;
>       filter: flipv fliph;
>   }
> </style>
> </head>
> <body>
>   <textarea class="verticaltext"/></textarea>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

While reading values form the `textarea` you may have to split it and get each character.
You may apply this css to `div` elements also.

Comment: Please try it in Internet Explorer